Google wallet and webhook
there,
Are there any webhooks for google wallet passes?
For example when a user deletes a pass from his wallet.
For the moment, I have to do daily and unitary queries to have the status of all the passes I have in the database in order to have the closest follow-up.

Companies like PassNinja and PassKit offer webhooks for Google wallet passes: https://www.passninja.com/documentation#webhook-payload

Also, at least for generic passes, Google offers it as well: https://developers.google.com/wallet/reference/rest/v1/CallbackOptions
